# Generating PDF in Codeigniter 4 - outputs weird characters

Tags: php, tcpdf, codeigniter-4

I'm generating a PDF document in my Codeigniter4 application.

I installed TCPDF via composer: `composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf`

My pdf is created the standard way, nothing fancy there.

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8');
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 10);
$pdf->SetTextColor(33, 65, 108);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
...
```

Everything is working as expected unless I try to output the PDF.

`$pdf->Output("file.pdf", 'D');` gives me the option to download the file and it is a correct PDF file as I would wish.

But if I try to output it directly in the browser:

`$pdf->Output("file.pdf", 'I');`

In the output I get weird characters. Looks like the document binary content is echoed to the browser, ignoring the header Content-Type.
I'm not sure, but i think it is a Codeigniter 4 issue, because in CI3 this code works, also not using CI, just plain PHP gives me the desired result.

What's wrong with CI4, is there some option to turn on?

Comment: can you check what headers you're getting in that output? Maybe Codeigniter output is overwriting that and setting that as the default output. If so, maybe you can set the correct headers yourself with this: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/response.html?highlight=output#setting-the-output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @marcogmonteiro suggested, I have to force CI to output the correct headers:

```
$this->response->setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
$pdf->Output("file.pdf", 'I');
```